# pip cannot install or upgrade, with UnicodeDecodeError reported

Tags: python, cmd, pip, decode, gbk

I am using anaconda Powershell Prompt in Win10. UnicodeDecodeError was reported when installing package with pip (version: 21.2.4). I found this error would reported with the kernel Python 3.6.7 and Python 3.9.7.Both the installation and the upgrade failed and reported the same error. I've tried the following command.

```
 pip install simplejson

 pip install simplejson --upgrade
```

The package can be anything and report the same bug.

Same error was reported using the Windows CMD. I tried the following command using Windows CMD.

```
py -m pip install simplejson

py -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Here is the error report I got.

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 173, in _main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 203, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 315, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 94, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 472, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 341, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 140, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 128, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 29, in _iter_built
    for version, func in infos:
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 272, in iter_index_candidate_infos
    result = self._finder.find_best_candidate(
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 851, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 798, in find_all_candidates
    page_candidates = list(page_candidates_it)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\sources.py", line 134, in page_candidates
    yield from self._candidates_from_page(self._link)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 758, in process_project_url
    html_page = self._link_collector.fetch_page(project_url)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 490, in fetch_page
    return _get_html_page(location, session=self.session)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 400, in _get_html_page
    resp = _get_html_response(url, session=session)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 115, in _get_html_response
    resp = session.get(
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\session.py", line 454, in request
    return super().request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 528, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\models.py", line 320, in prepare
    self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\models.py", line 556, in prepare_auth
    r = auth(self)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\auth.py", line 208, in __call__
    url, username, password = self._get_url_and_credentials(req.url)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\auth.py", line 180, in _get_url_and_credentials
    username, password = self._get_new_credentials(original_url)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\auth.py", line 145, in _get_new_credentials
    netrc_auth = get_netrc_auth(original_url)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 216, in get_netrc_auth
    _netrc = netrc(netrc_path).authenticators(host)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\netrc.py", line 30, in __init__
    self._parse(file, fp, default_netrc)
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\netrc.py", line 39, in _parse
    toplevel = tt = lexer.get_token()
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\shlex.py", line 109, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\shlex.py", line 140, in read_token
    nextchar = self.instream.read(1)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence
```

I have reinstalled the pip, Anaconda, and the python interpreter. It still failed. I think it has nothing to do with the pip. Something went wrong with the input stream. The default decode format is "GBK". I tried to change decode format to "utf-8" with the following command. It failed again with the same error.

```
chcp 65001
```

Thanks the suggestion from @Mobfi, I tried other similar commands, which return the same error notification.

```
chcp 437
chcp 850
```

Thanks the suggestion from @BoarGules, I start python with utf-8 decoder and tried to install/upgrade package with pip.

```
py -X utf8
```

I started the python console in powershell.
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'simplejson'])

Besides the similar traceback, I got another new traceback:

```
*same as aforementioned traceback*
File "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Anybody can help? Any potential solution, clues or similar experiences is welcomed.

Comment: The `0xff in position 0` is probably a byte order mark. So the file is probably UTF-16  though under Windows it is possibly also UTF-8.  Your message indicates that the code is expecting the file to be in `gbk`.  Python opens text files using the encoding `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` and on Windows that value is installation dependent. Futzing with `chcp` won't  change that. That command affects only the current console setting. You can override what `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` returns by starting Python with `-X utf8`.

Comment: Thanks @BoarGules, it returns similar error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte".